# How to create Installable Package for MS Word for Mac?

Tags: macos, ms-word, add-in, word-addins

I am creating a Word Add-ins For Mac OS. It working fine after Deploy on Office Admin Center but I am facing one challenge is I have to build a plug and play (Installable) Package like **.exe** in Windows Machine.

Is there any such way from that I can achieve that below are my machine details?

**OS**: Windows 10

**Processor**: i5 Processor

Comment: You can target macOS or your can target Windows 10. Which is it? Your post is confusing.

Comment: Thanks, @JohnKorchok,
Yes, I have a developing machine for Windows but I have to deploy it into macOS.

Comment: You could check out the installer that built into XCode. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/ Modern versions of macOS include GateKeeper that makes it more complex for a user to install software unless it coming from Apple or a developer registered with Apple. You'll really need to test on a Mac, you should be able buy a used Mac Mini on eBay for $400 or less.